# Using angular pipes with prime-ng multiselect

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a simple multi-select drop down which i want to apply a lowercase pipe for both selection area and the dropdown options. I've tried to do so with the following example - but it's not working - only the dropdown options "receives" the pipe transformation

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1" defaultLabel="Select a City" optionLabel="name">
<ng-template let-country pTemplate="item">
    <div class="country-item">
        <div>{{country.name | lowercase}}</div> // not working
    </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-item pTemplate="country">

    <div>{{item.name | lowercase}}</div> // working

</ng-template>
```

Perhaps it's related to the optionLabel="name" attribute?

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-gfdusm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, this solution will suit you (style it for youself):

```
<h5>Basic</h5>
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1" defaultLabel="Select a City" optionLabel="name">
    <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItems">
        <div class="country-item" *ngFor="let country of selectedCities1">
            <div>{{country.name | lowercase}}</div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!selectedCities1 || selectedCities1.length === 0" class="country-placeholder">
        Select a city
    </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="country">

        <div>{{item.name | lowercase}}</div>

    </ng-template>

</p-multiSelect>
```